# query table with dynamic fields

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have a table with the structure in the image. A post is conformed by all the rows with the same lead_id (17 fields in total). That said, how can I filter posts by a field_value? For instance query all the posts that has the field_value "ibague". Doing that with that table structure seems to be tricky. I was thinking of creating another table with primary key lead_id and create a column for every one of the 17 fields, and exporting the data with some horrible cursor in mysql, or some loop in php, and then make the query in a table easier to query. But with that approach I would have to create manually another column if a new field is added, and export the new data every time someone access to the report module. Any ideas my fellow programmers?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common dilemma in database design: flexibility vs easy to search. Your current table structure is optimised towards flexibility. Whether this is good for your current application or not we cannot tell, that's a decision you have to make.

However, you can search for forms within your current structure as well:

```
select lead_id
from yourtable
where `value`='ibague'
and form_id=1 and field_number=73 --not clear from your description if these conditions are needed
```

If you need all field values for a given lead where one of the fields match the search criteria, then place the above query into a subselect:

```
select * from yourtable t1
inner join (
    select distinct lead_id
    from yourtable
    where `value`='ibague'
    and form_id=1 and field_number=73) t2 on t1.lead_id=t2.lead_id
```

If form_id is also needed for the match, then include it both in the select list of the subquery and in the `on` clause of the join.

If you decide to flatten the data structure, then there is no need for complicated cursors, just use a technique called [dynamic pivoting or cross tabulated query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfect. Actually that data is from a wordpress plugin in which users create custom forms... thank you Shadow for the dynamic pivoting link too!!!!!!!